# optimise gulp Sass compiling

Tags: css, optimization, sass, gulp, compass

I have next situation. 
I have  **core.scss** file:

```
@import "fonts";
@import "custom_mixins";
@import "variables";
@import "base";
```

where I generally add all subfiles into one central.
Next with compass and gulp I compile this file:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/src/core.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: './config.rb',
            css: 'css/dist',
            sass: 'css/src'
        }));
});
```

It works fine but here I have the problem. Each time I change for example one line in **_variables.scss**, this task recompiles all files to **core.css** file. It takes near 2s for one line change. Is there any way I can cache *unchaged scss* subfiles so that they wont be recompiled each time?
I know there is an option in Gulp using *gulp-remember* plugin to remember compiled *unchanged css* files before concatenating them. But here I have one css file created from one scss file...

Comment: You really need Compass? Why not use gulp-sass that use libsass and is faster than the compilation with Compass?

Comment: I have task to use compass... But if using sass has option to optimise the task - please tell me what should I do...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use **gulp-sass** instead of compass. Compass is just a bunch of mixins and functions you can yourself integrate in your files without the need to compass dependency. Gulp-sass is faster than the sass compilation with Ruby because is using libsass, a port of Sass in C++.

First you'll need to install node-sass with NPM or [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and call it in your Gulpfile.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
```

You'll change your compass task to the sass version:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('css/src/core.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'nested'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/dist')
});
```

Try, your compilation will probably be faster. You can change sass options, add sourcemaps and others options.

Comment: Is there any way to ignore not changed subfiles imported via @import directive?

Comment: Not sure using gulp-cached or gulp-remember will work, gulp-sass-inheritance seems to be the best option to rebuild only changed sass files.

Comment: With gulp-sass you could also ignore specific files so that they don't compile within the source, for example gulp.src(['!css/src/ignorethis.scss', 'css/src/dontignorethis.scss'])

Comment: @DavidDias also I think you don't need semicolons after the on('error') and the last .pipe()